# How to use fitdist() result in a lm?

Tags: r, regression, distributions

I have used the `fitdist` function from `fitdistrplus` package to fit my data to a Gamma distribution and the output is a `fitdist` list object. How could I then use this list to apply a linear model to my data? Obviously I need them in a column fashion, but functions like `as.data.frame()` are of no help (impossible to coerce). Is there a way to apply the Gamma estimate from `fitdist` to the value to obtain the needed column?

Comment: I think it would be better just to use the raw data to fit the linear model.

Comment: But my professor told me to use this kind of distribution as it best suited the data. as I use the raw data (not normally distributed) the residuals look really terrible.

Comment: You could try a generalized linear model with the appropriate link function for the gamma distribution.

Comment: Probably you are expected to use gamma regression (?).  This can be done with the glm function,  something like `Model = glm( Y ~ X, data=Data, family="Gamma")` .  And, yes, Data is the data frame with the raw values.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I tried to apply the `glm` but the t-value has a strange repeating outcome of 1.942 for all my coefficients. As well the random effect is not computed ("coefficient not defined because of singularities"). my formula looks like this `glmer( Y ~ -1 + X + (1 | Random), data = Data, family="Gamma")`

Comment: I don't know if original poster is still here any more/still wants an answer, but if they gave more detail about the problems they're running into (ideally with a **reproducible** example, we might be able to help.  Otherwise I'm voting to close as "need more detail"

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be confusing different concepts.

fitdist is saying that your sample of data comes from a specific distribution lets say gamma with parameters a and b that is to say your data $X \sim \Gamma(a,b)$. fitdist then attempts to find the values for a and b that mostly closely match your data.

Linear models by the lm function on the other hand are saying that your data comes strictly from a normal distribution and that the mean of each data point is derived from a linear equation of what ever covariate values you also have that is to say $X \sim N( \mu_i , \sigma) $ where $\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \dots$.

If you were to set fitdist to fit a normal distribution then in theory you would get the same result as if you were to fit a linear model with only the intercept term.

So I guess at the moment a better question is what are you actually trying to achieve here? If you are trying to perform a linear model based on a gamma distribution then I would say you need to forget using fitdist and focus on using the `glm` function as mentioned by one of the commenters.